# How to print smile emoticon from right to left reverse using assembly

Tags: assembly, printing, character

How to Print Smile Emoticon from right to left in assembler

```
#MAKE_COM#        ; .com
ORG    100h  
START:  
   MOV  AH, 0     ; screen 80x25
   MOV  AL, 2     ; character 'smiley face'     
   INT  10h   ; set screen (and clear screen)  
   MOV  DX, 0     ; start position 0,0 (DH dan DL)  
   MOV  CX, 1     ; print 1 character  
set_kursor:  
   MOV  AH, 2  
   INT  10h        ; set cursor position  
   MOV  AH, 10  
   INT  10h    ; print character  
   INC  DH     ; to right  
   INC  DL     ; enter 1 row
   CMP  DH, 25     
   JNE  set_kursor ; try it
   RET             ; finish

END
```

the code does this

```
☺
 ☺
  ☺
   ☺
    ☺
     ☺
      ☺
```

What I want is the reverse like this

```
              ☺
             ☺
            ☺
           ☺
          ☺
         ☺
        ☺
```

Comment: Please edit your question: 1) Format the code (mark it and click on the appropriate button), 2) add tags (I guess: [emu8086] & [dos]).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to fix English issues.  I also marked down your code using 4 leading spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
INC  DH     ; to right  
INC  DL     ; enter 1 row
```

These comments are wrong! The DL register has the column and the DH register has the row.

To solve your question, first put the cursor at a position far enough to the right. I chose column 30 and row 0. Then on each iteration decrement the column value in DL register. As before increment the row value in DH register and exit after processing 25 rows:

```
#MAKE_COM#        ; .com
ORG    100h  
START:  
   MOV  AH, 0     ; screen 80x25
   MOV  AL, 3    
   INT  10h       ; set screen (and clear screen)  
   MOV  DX, 30    ; start position 30,0  
   MOV  CX, 1     ; print 1 character
   mov  bh, 0     ; display page 0
set_kursor:  
   MOV  AH, 2  
   INT  10h       ; set cursor position  
   MOV  AL, 2     ; character 'smiley face'     
   MOV  AH, 10
   INT  10h       ; print character  
   dec  dl        ; 1 column left 
   inc  dh        ; 1 row down
   CMP  DH, 25     
   JNE  set_kursor
   RET             ; finish

END
```